# How to add event when 3d object clicked in flutter

Tags: flutter, opengl, 3d, flutter-animation, flutter-canvas

I want a package to display a 3D object with the event of pressing the object, where it applies a function when the user clicks on the object.

I used the flutter_cube package but it doesn't have events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Can I build 3D (OpenGL) apps with Flutter?](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#can-i-build-3d-opengl-apps-with-flutter)

> Today we don’t support for 3D via OpenGL ES or similar. We have long-term plans to expose an optimized 3D API, but right now we’re focused on 2D.